# MarkLogic: convert string to path expression in cts:search

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

How can I create a function in **MarkLogic** that takes an **XPath** as a string and then passes it to the `cts:search` function?

I want to do something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace local = "http://www.local.com/" ;

declare function local:xpath-search($xpath as xs:string, $collection as xs:string, $limit  as xs:string) {
let $valid := cts:valid-index-path($xpath,fn:false())
let $results := cts:search(xdmp:value($xpath), cts:and-query(()) ) [position() < 100]
return 
    if ($valid = false()) then "xpath is invalid"
    else (
        if ($results = '') then "no results were found"
             else $results
        )
    } ;


local:xpath-search('//p', '', '')
```

But, I'm getting the "expression is unsearchable" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search and supply it with the `<searchable-expression>` option.

The `search:search` function already implements what you want. Under the hood it calls `cts:search` and supplies the searchable-expression using `xdmp:value`. You could do that to, but `search:search` has already been written and tested.

In passing, using path-based searchable expressions with `cts:search` is something of a trap for the unwary. In most cases it is better to use `collection()` as the first argument to `cts:search`, matching the entire database. Then use a `cts:query` for the second parameter, to match the documents you are interested in.

But what about `//p`? It's important to understand that MarkLogic indexes *fragments*, not elements. By default, fragments are documents. You can change that: you can even fragment at the `//p` level. But in most cases it's a bad idea. You're probably better off using `cts:search` to match documents, and `cts:highlight` to find matches in paragraphs. The `search:search` function supports that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Cascavel:

You could try expressing the entire cts:search() as a string (concatenating the static parts with the path) and invoking it with xdmp:value or xdmp:eval.

- http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value
- http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum